# linux: location of folders shared between group

Tags: linux

What's the best location for a folder intended to be used as a group storage location?  In other words, I want a folder called "examplefolder" belonging to a group named "examplegroup" that can be accessed by everyone in that group.  Is home/examplefolder the best location or elsewhere?

**Edit**:

The folder needs read and write permissions, so /usr would not work.  Does anyone think /var would be appropriate?  What about something in the root like shared?  Is there a reason not to use /home/examplefolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`man hier`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier), `/usr` would be appropriate if the data is going to be read only for other users. You don't **have to** strictly follow a specific hierarchy, although suggested. Personally all of my shared documents reside under a separate drive which I mounted at`/shared` and publish via Samba and also export with NFS. Storing it on a separate physical disk keeps my main disk quick and free of that activity regardless of who is accessing the share and how much they are transferring. Just make sure you set the permissions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks... the directory needs to be read/write though (see my edit).  Maybe /var would be appropriate.  What do you think?  I know I can do whatever I want, but I'm trying to get a sense of what's conventional.

Comment: @deuberger: For a more in-depth discussion, see the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

Comment: Just to clarify some things: if it's under `/home` it doesn't necessarily mean that it can't be mounted from another partition or hard drive.

Comment: Nobody ever said it can't? =S

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no raison do to else, even if your */home* is on a separated partition, containing all your ìn-site jobs, doing so ensure that backuping /home could stay a separated process of maintaining system.

Instead you could create your own hierarchy: hier.7 man page say:

```
BUGS
    This list is not exhaustive; different systems may be configured differently.
```

Like modifiing */etc/adduser.conf* for pointing another directory containing users' home
directories (DHOME) so:

```
DHOME=/home/users
```

than you could put your group directory to */home/groups/examplefolder*

You can even create */enterpriseprivatestorage* on separate partition,
*/enterpriseprivatestorage/users*, */enterpriseprivatestorage/works* and
*/enterpriseprivatestorage/shares* than finally */enterpriseprivatestorage/shares/examples*
and modifing */etc/adduser.conf* for setting `DHOME=/enterpriseprivatestorage/users`...

... has you want! (but prefferably no */usr*, */var* or any reserved by hier.7 manpage)